Trying to traverse a linked list in Python 3
I have a weird issue being able to traverse through a custom linked list. Here is the code for traversal.
from typing import Optional

class ListNode:

    def __init__(self, val, next_node=None):

        self.val = val
        self.next_node = next_node

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.val

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Value={self.val}, Next node available={self.next_node.value if self.next_node != None else -1}"

    __dict__ = ("val", "next_node",)

class Solution:

    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[list]:

        result_arr = []

        l1_running = l1 != None
        curr_node = l1

        print("***** Start traversing L1 only ******")
        while l1_running:
            print(curr_node)
            if curr_node.next_node:
                l1_running = True
                curr_node = curr_node.next_node
            else:
                l1_running = False
                curr_node = None

        print("***** End traversing L1 only ******")
        print(result_arr)
        return result_arr

    def list_node_builder(self, l1: list[str], l2: list[int]) -> list[int]:

        print("***** Start building Linked List ******")
        l1_list_nodes = []
        l2_list_nodes = []

        for index, num in enumerate(l1):
            if index == len(l1) - 1:
                new_node = ListNode(num)
                l1_list_nodes.append(new_node)
                print(new_node)
            else:
                new_node = ListNode(num, ListNode(l1[index+1]))
                print(str(new_node))
                l1_list_nodes.append(new_node)

        for index, num in enumerate(l2):
            if index == len(l2) -1:
                l2_list_nodes.append(ListNode(num))
            else:
                l2_list_nodes.append(ListNode(num, ListNode(l2[index+1])))

        print("***** Done building Linked List ******")
        return self.addTwoNumbers(l1_list_nodes[0], l2_list_nodes[0])

When I am trying to call this using the following code:
from addNumbers import Solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Solution()
    print(s.list_node_builder(l1=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"], l2=[9,9,9,1]))

My output is like this:
/Users/shyam/codespaces/python_projects/.venv/bin/python /Users/shyam/codespaces/python_projects/index.py 
***** Start building Linked List ******
Value=a, Next node available=b
Value=b, Next node available=c
Value=c, Next node available=d
Value=d, Next node available=e
Value=e, Next node available=f
Value=f, Next node available=g
Value=g, Next node available=-1
***** Done building Linked List ******
***** Start traversing L1 only ******
Value=a, Next node available=b
Value=b, Next node available=-1
***** End traversing L1 only ******
[]
[]

Process finished with exit code 0

I am not able to understand why building the linked list looks fine and the next_node is properly set, but when I traverse the list using the head, I get stopped out on the 2nd node.

That's because you're trying to link the nodes in the linked list with the items in the static list that you're passing to list_node_builder. You should add a node to the 1l_list_nodes, then when adding a new node, link the last node to the current node. Here's the code (this should answer your question, you still have to make changes to the rest of the code accordingly):
from typing import Optional

class ListNode:

    def __init__(self, val, next_node=None):

        self.val = val
        self.next_node = next_node

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.val

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Value={self.val}, Next node available={self.next_node.value if self.next_node != None else -1}"

    __dict__ = ("val", "next_node",)

class Solution:

    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[list]:

        result_arr = []

        l1_running = l1 != None
        curr_node = l1

        print("***** Start traversing L1 only ******")
        while l1_running:
            print(curr_node)
            if curr_node.next_node:
                l1_running = True
                curr_node = curr_node.next_node
            else:
                l1_running = False
                curr_node = None

        print("***** End traversing L1 only ******")
        print(result_arr)
        return result_arr

    def list_node_builder(self, l1: list[str], l2: list[int]) -> list[int]:

        print("***** Start building Linked List ******")
        l1_list_nodes = []
        l2_list_nodes = []

        # Here
        for index, num in enumerate(l1):
            new_node = ListNode(num)
            l1_list_nodes.append(new_node)
            if index !=0:
                l1_list_nodes[index-1].next_node = l1_list_nodes[index]

        for index, num in enumerate(l2):
            new_node = ListNode(num)
            l2_list_nodes.append(new_node)
            if index !=0:
                l2_list_nodes[index-1].next_node = l2_list_nodes[index]

        print("***** Done building Linked List ******")
        return self.addTwoNumbers(l1_list_nodes[0], l2_list_nodes[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Solution()
    print(s.list_node_builder(l1=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"], l2=[9,9,9,1]))




Your problem is at this line:
new_node = ListNode(num, ListNode(l1[index + 1]))

When the index is 0, you build a ListNode(l1[1]) first (which has no next_node), and then you build a ListNode('a', ListNode(l1[1])) (which has next_node), so the next node of this node will be certainly ListNode(l1[1]) without an next_code.
I agreed with eternal_white's answer about the solution of this problem.

As others indicated, you provided an entry from the original list as value for next_node, but that means you assign an int to an attribute that is supposed to be a ListNode.
As you need to populate two linked lists, it makes sense to create a function to does that job for one, and then call it twice. Also, it seems more elegant to populate a linked list from end to start:
# Helper function to create a linked list from a standard list
def to_list_nodes(lst: list) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    head = None
    for val in reversed(lst):
        head = ListNode(val, head)
    return head
        
class Solution:
    # ...
    def list_node_builder(self, l1: List[str], l2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        l1_list_nodes = to_list_nodes(l1)
        l2_list_nodes = to_list_nodes(l2)

Not your question, but:

for a traversal you don't need this l1_running variable, nor an if ... else switch in the loop body. That loop can be as simple as:
    while curr_node:
        print(curr_node)
        curr_node = curr_node.next_node


It would seem more logical if addTwoNumbers would return a linked list instead of a standard list, and that another function would convert that linked list to a list. Anyhow, the name of this function suggests there is still some work to do here. Maybe you can benefit from this answer or this answer that seem to cover the same addTwoNumbers method.


